# HQL - get results from select with DOT seperator

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Is it possible to get HQL results with dot.
for example:

```
select Employee.name as 'Employee.name'
```

I know that mysql allows that, is there any support fir that in hibernate.
This is the exeption that I get:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: . near line 1, column 42 [SELECT Affiliate.affiliateId as Affiliate.affiliateId , parent.userName as parent_userName , Affiliate.userName as Affiliate_userName , Affiliate.email as Affiliate_email , parent.affiliateId as parent_affiliateId , employee.firstName as employee_firstName , Affiliate.name as Affiliate_name FROM com.affiliates.hibernate.Affiliate Affiliate  INNER JOIN Affiliate.employee as employee  INNER JOIN Affiliate.parent as parent WHERE 1=1  AND Affiliate.employee='1']
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
```

Because of architecture problems, "_" instad of "." cant work for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. You are thinking about writing queries. Hibernate supports its internal language called HQL. To be honest I prefer using JPA and hibernate as JPA implementation. In such case you have to write your queries with [Criteria Api](http://www.developer.com/java/ent/article.php/10933_3893771_2/Criteria-Queries-in-JPA-20-and-Hibernate-The-APIs-Have-It.htm) or using [JPA query language](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbtg.html). Query language is very convenient in conjunction with [NamedQueries](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/NamedQuery.html). So if you are using HQL or JPA, the easiest way is to select object with some name

```
SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE p.name = ?1
```

The other possibility is using [NativeQuery](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery%28java.lang.String%29), here is an [example](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2007/08/22/jpa-tip-1-native-queries).